# how to put a video fit in the center of screen whatever width of the screen is used?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

i'm using jquery mobile and i want to put a video fit in the center of screen no matter what width of the screen. i used this syntax, but the left margin and right margin are not same. [

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div data-role="header"></div>
  
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <span style="position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left:-150px; margin-top: -150px;">
        <video width="block" height="auto"   id="video_mute" controls>
          <source src="angka/bilangan_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%); for center

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>

<body>

  <div data-role="header">
  </div>
  
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" >
 <span style="position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);">
    <video width="block" height="auto"   id="video_mute" controls>
  <source src="angka/bilangan_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: it works, thank you. the problem now is when i try to open this page from another html file by link, this page can't open, it just loads. please help me.

Comment: I am not understaning you issue,can you tell me in details.....in other html page you need to copy code from here paste there.....it will work

Comment: so, i will run your syntax above and i named it ali.html. i will open ali.html using a button in index.html ( a href="ali.html"), but it's so slow loading even it can't open the ali.html.

Comment: maybe your video path is not proper because I changed span style only in your code.....so try your code with only span css replace from here.

Comment: i have used span css but it still just loading, it can't open the page. it looks like the page is heavy, whereas i just use those syntax.

Comment: yes, i have and when i launch my page to my browser, it can open, but if i try to open this page from index, it just loading, it can't open.

Comment: @okt Most Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` instead of margin. check updated snippet below...

```css
.videoDiv {
  position: fixed; 
  left: 50%; 
  top: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div data-role="header">
</div>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" >
  <span class="videoDiv" style="">
    <video width="block" height="auto"   id="video_mute" controls>
      <source src="angka/bilangan_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </span>
</div>
```